# Image not displaying on the localhost

Tags: python-3.x, image, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

```
class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False,
                           default='profile.jpg')
```

I changed the name of the image file like from 'default.jpg' to 'profile.jpg'.
But the image is not displaying on the localhost as the default value of the image was set to 'default.jpg' in the User Model in Flask.So its asking the localhost to get from this location

```
"GET /static/img/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

So can anyone provide me a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this only happens to the existing user in your database, if you create a new user there shouldn't be a problem. The default value you set only apply to new User objects, it applies when you create a new User without specifying the image file. So for the existing user in your database, the value of image_file has already been set as "default.jpg" and has nothing to do with your subsequent modification in Flask model.

To change the value of image_file of existing user, you can either write a view function to modify the value in a browser, or you can simply connect to your database and change the value directly. For example if you use SQLite, you can try [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), open your local db file and modify the value with a user-friendly GUI.

Comment: Yeah, it happened when I created a new registration. Thanks for your help